# Configure Git to notify about stashed changes

Tags: git, git-stash

Is it possible to configure Git to remind me that my stash is not empty when I'm launching some Git commands, let's say, for example, when I'm switching branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some commands can invoke [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Switching branches is usually done by `git checkout <branch>`. The hook `post-checkout` is invoked if it exists and is executable when `git checkout` is run. Copy the following script and paste to `.git/hooks/post-checkout`, and run `chmod 755 .git/hooks/post-checkout`.

```
#!/bin/bash

oldrev=$1
newrev=$2
flag=$3

# list stashes if switching branches
if [[ "${flag}" = 1 ]];then
    git stash list
fi
```

Then when you run `git checkout <branch>`, `git stash list` will be run and print the stash entries if any.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing! We got it faster...! :D